# Serving retrained Tensorflow Hub module with new features

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-hub

I have trained a Tensorflow model using estimators and TF Hub Elmo word embedding + new features, and have been trying to get it working with Tensorflow Serving for predictions. When I try to run a prediction, I get the following error:

```js
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 49, in <module>
    run(args.host, args.port, args.text, args.model, args.signature_name)
  File "client.py", line 29, in run
    response = stub.Predict(request, 10.0)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 500, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 434, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION, Serving signature key "serving_default" not found.)>
```

Here are all the relevant files needed to reproduce the steps:

```
train.py
```

```html
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import json
import urllib

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer(
    'steps', 10, 'The number of steps to train a model')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
    'model_dir', './models/ckpt/', 'Dir to save a model and checkpoints')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
    'saved_dir', './models/pb/', 'Dir to save a model for TF serving')
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

'''
Data loading and preprocessing method
Dropped rows that do not contain sentiment
Casted text column to all lowercase to normalize tweets
Created new feature column for tweets containing a website or link
Created new feature column to check for profanity from a text file
'''


def load_and_preprocess():
    data = pd.read_csv('https://www.figure-eight.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Apple-Twitter-Sentiment-DFE.csv',
                       encoding="ISO-8859-1")
    data['text'] = data['text'].str.lower()
    data = data[data.sentiment.str.contains("not_relevant") == False]
    data['contains_url'] = data['text'].str.contains('http').astype(int)
    profanity = pd.read_fwf('data/profanity.txt', header=None)
    words = [any(i in words for i in profanity[0].values)
             for words in data['text'].str.split().values]
    words = np.array(words, dtype=np.float32)
    data['contains_profanity'] = words.astype(int)
    sentiment = data['sentiment']
    text = data['text']
    url = data['contains_url']
    profanity = data['contains_profanity']

    return data, sentiment, text, url, profanity


data, sentiment, text, url, profanity = load_and_preprocess()


def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    feature_spec = {
        "text": tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None]),
        "url": tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.bool, shape=[None]),
        "profanity": tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.bool, shape=[None]),
    }
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(feature_spec, feature_spec)


def main(unused_argv):
    train_size = int(len(text) * .8)
    train_text = text[:train_size]
    train_sentiment = sentiment[:train_size]
    train_url = url[:train_size]
    train_profanity = profanity[:train_size]

    test_text = text[train_size:]
    test_sentiment = sentiment[train_size:]
    test_url = url[train_size:]
    test_profanity = profanity[train_size:]

    text_embeddings = hub.text_embedding_column(
        "text",
        module_spec="https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2", trainable=True
    )

    encoder = MultiLabelBinarizer()
    encoder.fit_transform(train_sentiment)
    train_encoded = encoder.transform(train_sentiment)
    test_encoded = encoder.transform(test_sentiment)
    num_classes = len(encoder.classes_)

    multi_label_head = tf.contrib.estimator.multi_label_head(
        num_classes,
        loss_reduction=tf.losses.Reduction.SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE
    )

    estimator = tf.contrib.estimator.DNNEstimator(
        head=multi_label_head,
        hidden_units=[64, 10],
        feature_columns=[text_embeddings],
        model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir
    )

    # Format our data for the numpy_input_fn
    features = {
        "text": np.array(train_text),
        "url": np.array(train_url),
        "profanity": np.array(train_profanity)
    }
    labels = np.array(train_encoded)

    train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        features,
        labels,
        shuffle=True,
        batch_size=FLAGS.steps,
        num_epochs=10
    )

    estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn)
    estimator.export_savedmodel(
        FLAGS.saved_dir, serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)

    eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({"text": np.array(
        test_text).astype(np.str)}, test_encoded.astype(np.int32), shuffle=False)
    estimator.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.app.run()
```

```
client.py
```

```html
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from grpc.beta import implementations
import argparse

from tensorflow_serving.apis import predict_pb2
from tensorflow_serving.apis import prediction_service_pb2
from tensorflow_serving.apis import classification_pb2


def run(host, port, text, model, signature_name):
    text = "My cat only chews @apple cords. Such an #AppleSnob.".encode()
    url = np.array([0]).astype(np.bool)
    profanity = np.array([0]).astype(np.bool)

    # establish a connection
    channel = implementations.insecure_channel(host, port)
    stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel)

    request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
    request.model_spec.name = 'elmo'
    request.model_spec.signature_name = signature_name

    request.inputs['text'].CopyFrom(tf.make_tensor_proto(text))
    request.inputs['url'].CopyFrom(tf.make_tensor_proto(url))
    request.inputs['profanity'].CopyFrom(tf.make_tensor_proto(profanity))

    response = stub.Predict(request, 10.0)
    print(response)


def parse_args(parser):


    options = parser.parse_args()
    return options


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--host", type=str, default="localhost")
    parser.add_argument("--port", type=int, default=8500)
    parser.add_argument("--text", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--model", type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--signature_name', default='serving_default', type=str)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    run(args.host, args.port, args.text, args.model, args.signature_name)
```

```
Dockerfile
```

```html
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        curl \
        libcurl3-dev \
        unzip \
        wget \
        && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Installing tensorflow-model-server
RUN TEMP_DEB="$(mktemp)" \
    && wget -O "$TEMP_DEB" 'http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt/pool/tensorflow-model-server-1.8.0/t/tensorflow-model-server/tensorflow-model-server_1.8.0_all.deb' \
    && dpkg -i "$TEMP_DEB" \
    && rm -f "$TEMP_DEB"

# gRPC port
EXPOSE 8500

# REST API port
EXPOSE 8501

# Serving the model
CMD tensorflow_model_server \
  --port=8500 \
  --rest_api_port=8501 \
  --model_name="$MODEL_NAME" \
  --model_base_path="$MODEL_PATH"
```

```
env.yml
```

```html
name: elmo
channels:
    - https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo
    - conda-forge
dependencies:
    - python=3
    - scikit-learn
    - protobuf
    - openblas
    - scipy
    - numpy
    - pandas
    - pillow
    - h5py
    - pip:
        - grpcio
        - grpcio-tools
        - tensorflow
        - tensorflow-serving-api
        - tensorflow-hub
        - flake8
```

```
Steps to reproduce
```

```html
1. conda env create -f env.yml
2. python train.py --steps 100 --saved_dir ./models/ --model_dir ./elmo_ckpt
  - This takes a while to train, so I have provided my repo with the model files already in it
3. docker build --rm -f Dockerfile -t tensorflow-elmo:latest .
4. docker run --rm -v ${PWD}/models:/models -e MODEL_NAME='elmo' -e MODEL_PATH='/models' -p 8500:8500 -p 8501:8501 --name tensorflow-server tensorflow-elmo:latest
5. python client.py --model elmo
```

I've tried with different options in the signature_name and the model was named after the Docker container, which I found out fixed some other peoples problems. Here's the repo with the trained model and checkpoint files already available, in the interest of time: [Repository with model files](https://gitlab.com/sadiq.quasem/twitter_sentiment_analysis)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're seeing is about a mismatch between the signatures in the SavedModel: the estimator does not write the one you are trying to serve. The [saved_model_cli](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#cli_to_inspect_and_execute_savedmodel) should help you inspect it.

Also, your code uses the long-obsolete tf.contrib.estimator and mixes it with tf.estimator. I highly recommend switching to tf.estimator throughout.

This seems unrelated to the use of TensorFlow Hub. By the time your estimator exports a model, all module contents have been inlined into it.

Comment: I already inspected the model and changed the signature name in the script, but it still gives me the same error, just changes the name.

Also, thanks for the pointer on the deprecated estimator calls, I'll update everything to the new version :)